# How to add policy setting in C# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am making a desktop app for an IoT based project. For this project I would like to add time based activities, like turning a device on or off at a particular time. All such activities will be grouped under a policy. How can I implement it by,

1. Keeping app running 24*7 ? Like check the present time and the time set in the app and do the corresponding activity.
2. Setting it somewhere in my Computer, so that the app need not run 24*7

Answer (score 1):

Create a windows service.

override "OnTimer" function to address time based activities.

Below is a very nice documentation from microsoft, regarding how to do it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have a GUI on which you can modify the settings. Will it affect my GUI ? Also can you explain "override "OnTimer" function to address time based activities" as I am new to app development ?

Comment: Yes can do that. Ensure GUI loads from service.The ontimer example in the link provided in answer.

Comment: The link doesnt explain about how to start my GUI (from service) or listening to GUI start event or even interacting with my GUI